# Example of $I$-adic topology of submodule not matching subspace topology?

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm reading about the $I$-adic topology on $M$ for $R$ a commutative ring, $I$ an ideal of $R$ and $M$ an $R$-module. The references I'm reading don't provide examples, but they say that if $N$ is a submodule of $M$, it's not necessarily true that the subspace topology of $N$ in $M$ with the $I$-adic topology coincides with the $I$-adic topology on $M$ (of course, I know this holds for $R$ Noetherian and $M$ a finite $R$-module by Artin-Rees).

Does anyone know of any specific examples where these topologies don't coincide? Thank you very much!

Comment: @user26857 posted essentially the following but deleted it: 

Let $R=\mathbb{Q}[x,z,y_1,y_2,…]/<x−zy_1,x−z^2y_2,…>$. Then take $M=R$, $N=(x)$, and $I=<z>$. Then $\cap_{i=1}^n I^n =(x)$, so $(\cap_{i=1}^n I^i\cap (x)) =(x)$ for all $n$, but ...

This looks promising but not quite there as far as I can tell. I could be missing something big, though.

Answer (score -3):

Look this for instance: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71699/counter-examples-to-krulls-intersection-theorem if it may help.

Comment: You mean Artin-Rees is a corollary of the Krull intersection theorem? I've only seen it (essentially) the other way around. Anyways, I'm not seeing completely the relevancy of the MathOverflow link you're posting : I don't see a module-submodule pair specified anywhere or the reasoning demonstrating why Artin-Rees fails.

Thanks!

Comment: @Darth_Algebra edited